# Валидация данных ajax запросом на spring контроллере

Tags: java, ajax, spring

Как можно реализовать в коде валидацию асинхронно не обновляя страницу?

У меня есть **spring** контроллер

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/main/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addBand(@ModelAttribute(value = "band") Band band,BindingResult bindingResult) {

    bandValidator.validate(band, bindingResult);

    if(bindingResult.hasErrors())
      return "main";

    if(band.getId() == 0)
      this.service.addBand(BandBreakADate.breakADate(band));

    else
      this.service.updateBand(band);

    return "redirect:/main";
}
```

На такой реализации контроллера если есть ошибки валидации страница перезагрузится, что не очень хорошо.

Узнал про **Ajax** но не могу найти информацию как сделать тоже самое но с помощью **Ajax**, валидировать данные с формы на сервере не обновляя страницу.

Comment: вы с javascript знакомы?

Comment: @Mikhail Vaysman Поверхностно знаком, у меня получалось одно поле валидировать ajax-ом, я не знаю как отправить на контроллер из скрипта целый объект с полями

Comment: тогда либо изучаете JS, либо подключаете какой-нибудь GWT или аналогичный фреймворк. я рекомендую выбрать первое.

Comment: @Mikhail Vaysman спасибо

Comment: Вы может просто форму отправить. Читайте документацию на mdn.